# iPhone shortcut to check whether URL is already open in Chrome

Tags: iphone, shortcuts-app, url

Because I use Chrome as my default browser (which does not allow for bookmarks in the Home Screen), I have created a bookmark using the Shortcuts app and the following commands:
`Open URL in Chrome`
`Stop this shortcut`

However this has the disadvantage of multiplying the number of open tabs if we do not diligently close previous ones.

**Is it possible to scan existing open tabs in Chrome using the Shortcuts app and search for a given URL?** This would allow me to only open a new Stack Exchange tab if there is none already open.